# Unusual behavior with Luhn's algorithm in C

Tags: c, cs50, luhn

I've been doing a CS50 course and stumbled upon this "Credit" problem. At the moment I'm testing it and due to insufficient cases provided in worksheet, I went to the recommended PayPal testing card numbers: https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/payflow/integration-guide/test-transactions/#standard-test-cards
Particularly:

- Mastercard `5555555555554444`
- Mastercard `5105105105105100`
- Mastercard `5199999999999991`
- Mastercard `5299999999999990`

These refuse to cooperate. My program calculates the Luhn's value for them, and it's not close to being a multiplier of 10; am I missing something, because other providers are working perfectly fine.

Results from code check:

```
:( identifies 5555555555554444 as MASTERCARD
    expected "MASTERCARD\n", not "114\nINVALID\n..."
:( identifies 5105105105105100 as MASTERCARD
    expected "MASTERCARD\n", not "47\nINVALID\n"
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int get_sum_from_second_to_last(long temp_number);

int get_sum_from_odd_digits(long temp_number);

int length(long temp_number);

int return_first_n_digits(int n, long temp_number, int length);

int main()
{
    int final_sum = 0;
    long number = 0;
    do
    {
        number = get_long("Number: ");
    }
    while(number<0);
    final_sum = get_sum_from_second_to_last(number) + get_sum_from_odd_digits(number);
    printf("%i\n", final_sum);
    if(final_sum % 10 == 0)
    {
        if(length(number) == 15 && (return_first_n_digits(2, number, length(number)) == 34 || return_first_n_digits(2, number, length(number)) == 37))
        {
            printf("AMEX\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if((length(number) == 16 || length(number) == 13) && return_first_n_digits(1, number, length(number)) == 4)
            {
                printf("VISA\n");
            }
            else
            {
                if(length(number) == 16 && (return_first_n_digits(2, number, length(number)) == 51 || return_first_n_digits(2, number, length(number)) == 52 || return_first_n_digits(2, number, length(number)) == 53 || return_first_n_digits(2, number, length(number)) == 54 || return_first_n_digits(2, number, length(number)) == 55))
                {
                    printf("MASTERCARD\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("This card provider recognition is not supported\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
}

int get_sum_from_second_to_last(long temp_number)
{
    int digit_current = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    do
    {
        digit_current = temp_number % 10;
        if(counter%2 == 0)
        {
            if((digit_current*2)%10!=0)
            {
                sum = sum + (digit_current*2)%10 + (digit_current*2)/10;
            }
            else
            {
                sum = sum + digit_current*2;
            }
        }
        temp_number = temp_number/10;
        counter += 1;
    }
    while(temp_number);
    return sum;
}

int get_sum_from_odd_digits(long temp_number)
{
    int digit_current = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    do
    {
        digit_current = temp_number % 10;
        if(counter%2 != 0)
        {
            sum = sum + digit_current;
        }
        temp_number = temp_number/10;
        counter += 1;
    }
    while(temp_number);
    return sum;
}

int length(long temp_number)
{
    int counter = 0;
    do
    {
        temp_number = temp_number/10;
        counter++;
    }
    while(temp_number);
    return counter;
}

int return_first_n_digits(int n, long temp_number, int length)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < length - n; i++)
    {
        temp_number = temp_number/10;
    }
    return temp_number;
}
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger?

Comment: You already have the digits in a string if you input that way. That makes it really easy to pick out individual digits. Numbers should not always to be treated as integers, especially phone numbers, card numbers, house number and PINs. Using integers vastly overcomplicates the analysis of the card number.

Comment: Treat the CCN as a string, not a number.  It's far simpler to process the decimal digits when they're already one digit per character.  So, avoid `get_long()`.

Comment: Note that `long` may only be 32-bit. `long long` is better.  A _string_ input is best here.

Comment: Yes, I've looked through the code multiple times, there should not be a mistake in code, but rather something external, because the Luhn's sum is calculated right. I thought about using string and I'm sure it's much easier, it's just that I'm very new to C, so didn't want to deal with chars and strings there, because afaik string is not a native class (?). Anyway, I just think I miss something very apparent, just can't see it

Comment: *something external* - The checker is clearly telling you that your program is printing "INVALID" instead of "MASTERCARD" for the given input. Did you try to feed this input to your program locally? Moreover, it has an extra output that is not expected (coming from `printf("%i\n", final_sum);` I presume).

Comment: "there should not be a mistake in code" Famous last words. "but rather something external" It's never something external, until proven otherwise. "Luhn's sum is calculated right" Obviously not. Have you tried to calculate the sum by hand? What's the Luhn's sum of 5555555555554444? (Spoiler: 60).

Comment: Yes, I did. Those card numbers just don't pass the Luhn's sum requirement, therefore my program is tossing INVALID. But that is quite strange, because I've checked my calculation and it should be right. Edit: Hm, then I'm going to check again, thanks for clarification! I guess my math on paper was wrong too :(

Comment: True, C does not have a string class, nor *any* classes. But strings are 'native' enough to be given an entire module of the standard library, and to be covered in the C standard. CS50 *isn't* helpful here with the way it hides the string as a pointer type, in the opinion of many practised C programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be in your function for summing up the even numbered digits in the `int get_sum_from_second_to_last` function.  In that function, the digits are multiplied by a factor of two.  Then according to information on how the Luhn's algorithm is supposed to work, if the result is a two-digit number, those digits are then supposed to be added together to derive a single digit. It appears that doesn't always happen with the current testing within that function.  Since the value of multiplying one digit by "2" can only result in two-digit numbers from "10" to "18", one can effectively derive the summation of the digits by just subtracting the value of "9" from the calculated result.

With that, I offer up the following code snippet as an alternative summation of the even-numbered digits.

```
int get_sum_from_second_to_last(long temp_number)
{
    int digit_current = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    do
    {
        digit_current = temp_number % 10;
        if(counter%2 == 0)
        {
            if((digit_current*2) > 9)
            {
                sum = sum + (digit_current * 2 - 9);
            }
            else
            {
                sum = sum + digit_current * 2;
            }
        }
        temp_number = temp_number/10;
        counter += 1;
    }
    while(temp_number);

    printf("Even digit sum: %d\n", sum);

    return sum;
}
```

FYI, you can leave out the `printf()` call.  I added that just for some visual clarification.

With that change, I tested out the four sample numbers in your narrative and they all produced a valid MASTERCARD result.

```
Number: 5299999999999990
Even digit sum: 64
Current digit: 0
Current digit: 9
Current digit: 9
Current digit: 9
Current digit: 9
Current digit: 9
Current digit: 9
Current digit: 2
Odd digit sum: 56
Final sum: 120
MASTERCARD
```

As a further test, I actually tested out a number for AMEX and for VISA and those worked as well.

I hope that clarifies things.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for correcting that typo Chris.  I must have muffed the copy/paste bit.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying things! Next time though I will make sure to use strings as per the recommendations in the initial comments.