# cs50 Credit project seems to work but the check50 tells me there are errors

Tags: c, cs50

I have a problem when checking my code with check50.  Most elements checked fine. Here are the errors I get when I run `check50 cs50/problems/2023/x/credit`

```
:( identifies 369421438430814 as INVALID (invalid identifying digits)
expected "INVALID\\n", not "AMEX\\n"

:( identifies 5673598276138003 as INVALID (invalid identifying digits)
expected "INVALID\\n", not "MASTERCARD\\n"
```

Here is my code:  Any ideas on why this is happening???

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int validate_card(long long creditCard);
int typeOfCard(long long creditCard);

int main(void)
{
    // Declare variables
    long long creditCard;
    // Prompt the user for a credit card number
    do
    {
        creditCard = get_long_long("Enter credit card number: ");
        bool value = validate_card(creditCard);
        // report Validity
        if (!value)
        {
            printf("INVALID\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    while (creditCard < 0);

    int count = typeOfCard(creditCard);

    // TODO: Implement Luhn's algorithm to check if the credit card number is valid
    // (You should break this down into steps, doubling every other digit and summing the digits)
}

int validate_card(long long creditCard)
{
    int sum = 0;
    bool isValid = false;
    int digitSum = 0;
    int otherSum = 0;
    bool isAlternateDigit = false;

    while (creditCard > 0)
    {
        if (isAlternateDigit == true)
        {
            int lastDigit = creditCard % 10;
            lastDigit = (lastDigit * 2);
            // if two digits, separate into two separate digits
            if (lastDigit > 9)
            {
                int first, last;
                first = (lastDigit / 10);
                last = (lastDigit % 10);

                digitSum = (first) + (last);
                lastDigit = digitSum;
            }
            sum = sum + lastDigit;
        }
        else
        {
            int lastDigit = creditCard % 10;
            otherSum = otherSum + lastDigit;
        }
        isAlternateDigit = !isAlternateDigit;
        creditCard = creditCard / 10;
    }
    sum = sum + otherSum;
    sum = sum % 10;
    if (sum % 10 == 0)
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}

int typeOfCard(long long creditCard)
{
    // Count digits
    long long creditCardCount = creditCard;
    int count = 0;

    // Get the last digit
    int lastDigit = 0;
    while (creditCardCount > 0)
    {
        lastDigit = creditCardCount % 10;
        creditCardCount = creditCardCount / 10;
        count++;
    }

    // Get the first digit
    creditCardCount = creditCard;
    int firstDigit = 0;
    while (creditCardCount > 9)
    {
        creditCardCount = creditCardCount / 10;
    }
    firstDigit = creditCardCount;

    // MASTERCARD
    if (firstDigit == 5 && count == 16)
    {
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }
    // AMEX
    else if (firstDigit == 3 && count == 15)
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
    // VISA
    else if (firstDigit == 4 && (count == 13 || count == 16))
    {
        printf("VISA\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }

    return count;
}
```

Here is a valid Amex number: `378282246310005`.  my code returns `AMEX`.  That is what I am expecting.  The error seems to indicate that is was expecting `INVALID`.

Same with MASTERCARD: here is a valid Mastercard number: `2221000000000009`

Comment: You can't use integers with any kind of number that could contain leading zeros. Use strings instead.

Comment: Notice that the numbers referred to in the error messages don't match those you cite at the bottom; if the latter are really when you enter, maybe you should track down why your code disagrees.

Comment: OT: In `typeOfCard` you calculate `lastDigit` but you never use it. Why?

Comment: OT: Your `do-while` seems strange. It kind of suggest that you want to keep reading input until the input isn't negative. However, you do call `validate_card` on negative input. Perhaps the code calling `validate_card` should be after the loop?

Comment: OT: `count` in `main` unused

Comment: this makes no sense to me.  I went online to a credit card validator and ran 369421438430814.  this proved to be a valid number.  Still the error says it is not

Comment: I am a true beginner.  All of those things are probably true but I fought my way through this code.  I will try to fix it.  Thanks.

Comment: Your typeOfCard function is wrong. It only checks the first digit and the length. This is not how it is supposed to work.

Comment: You don't need a loop to get the last digit. Just `lastDigit = creditCard % 10`.

Comment: As noted in an earlier comment, your testing and validation of credit card types is incomplete as the checks are just checking length and starting digit.  You may want to check out a very similar (if not the same) CS50 assignment question posed last year in which I had provided some insight  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72861726/unusual-behavior-with-luhns-algorithm-in-c/72862346#72862346".  You can see that there is additional validation functionality to be had for each type of credit card.